# How do I convert from JdbcRDD to SchemaRDD in Spark?

Tags: jdbc, apache-spark

I was able to import data from Hbase to Spark using [Phoenix JDBC driver](http://phoenix.apache.org/) and [JdbcRDD](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.JdbcRDD) using the code below, how do I convert from JdbcRDD to [SchemaRDD](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD) in order to use SparkSQL?

```
//SparkToJDBC.scala

import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd.JdbcRDD

object SparkToJDBC {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sc = new SparkContext("local", "phoenix")
    try{
            val rdd = new JdbcRDD(sc,() => {
                        Class.forName("org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver").newInstance()
                        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:phoenix:localhost", "", "")
                   },
                   "SELECT id, name  FROM test.orders WHERE id >= ? AND id <= ?",
                    1, 100, 3,
                    (r:ResultSet) => {
                                processResultSet(r)
                    }
                ).cache()

            println(rdd.count());

     } catch {
              case _: Throwable => println("Could not connect to database")
     }
     sc.stop()
  }

def processResultSet(rs: ResultSet){//TODO: return Row object as per JDBCRDD doc

          val rsmd = rs.getMetaData()
          val numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount()

            var i = 1
            while (i <= numberOfColumns) {
              val s = rs.getString(i)
              System.out.print(s + "  ")
              i += 1
            }
            println("")

   }

}
```

Edit: found alternative way via https://github.com/simplymeasured/phoenix-spark

Answer (score 1):

As JdbcRdd is an implementation of RDD, if you wanted create a SchemaRDD you only have to create an SQLContext and call a few methods:

```
val sc = new SparkContext("local", "phoenix")
val sqc = new SQLContext(sc)
try{
        val rdd = new JdbcRDD(sc,() => {
                    Class.forName("org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver").newInstance()
                    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:phoenix:localhost", "", "")
               },
               "SELECT id, name  FROM test.orders WHERE id >= ? AND id <= ?",
                1, 100, 3,
                (r:ResultSet) => {
                            processResultSet(r)
                }
            ).cache()
        val schemaRDD = sqc.createSchemaRDD(rdd)
}
```

With this code, schemaRDD will be an SchemaRDD[Unit] because you didn't do anything in the processResultSet method. So this code will crash because an SchemaRDD needs a T type that have to extend Product so if you do not process your ResulSet you cannot have an SchemaRDD

I hope this will be usefull for you.